# How to set file type and file transfer mode in JSch?

Tags: java, ftp, sftp, jsch, apache-commons-net

I used Apache Common Net `FTPClient` and had setup my `ftpClient` with methods shown below before upload file.

```
ftpClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
ftpClient.setFileTransferMode(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
```

Now I try to use JSch. Is there same setting needed before file uploading and how they looks like? Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, it is not clear from your question, whether you are aware that JSch and Apache Commons Net `FtpClient` each use completely different and unrelated protocols. JSch is an SSH/SFTP client, while `FtpClient` is an FTP client.

---

JSch uses an SFTP protocol version 3.

In the SFTP protocol version 3, there are no transfer modes. Or in other words, there is only the *binary* transfer mode.

And even if JSch used a newer version of SFTP protocol, which supports the *ascii* mode, the *binary* mode is the default anyway in SFTP.

*So you do not have to do anything.*

This is in a contrast to the FTP protocol, which defaults to the *ascii* mode. So you have explicitly switch to the *binary* mode with FTP (using the [`FTPClient.setFileType`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html#setFileType(int)) in case of the Apache Commons Net).

---

As for the [`FTPClient.setFileTransferMode`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html#setFileTransferMode(int)) – Your FTP code is wrong. The method accepts one of the `*_TRANSFER_MODE` constants. Never the `*_FILE_TYPE`. If you use `BINARY_FILE_TYPE`, it results in sending an invalid `MODE I` command to the server. Which for sure fails, and consequently has no effect at all. Check the method result code, it for sure returns `false`.

Remove the call from your FTP code. There is no need to call `FTPClient.setFileTransferMode`. Apache Commons Net supports only the default "stream" mode anyway (and most FTP servers do not support any other mode either).

---

Note the confusion in the names. The ascii/binary are commonly indeed called "transfer modes". But in FTP protocol specification (section 3.1.1 of [RFC 959](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc959)), they are actually called "data types" and are governed using `TYPE` command.

While what FTP specification calls "transmission modes", governed by `MODE` command (section 3.4), are completely different kind of modes: stream/block/compressed. They are hardly ever set or even mentioned.

As Apache Commons Net `FtpClient` confusingly names the method for setting "transmission mode" `.setFileTransferMode`, it frequently leads to the mistakes like you did – People incorrectly try to use `FTPClient.setFileTransferMode` to switch between the binary/ascii *"data types"*.

Comment: Thank you, very much, bro, you completely answered my question.