# How does Apache Camel support ASCII mode file transfer with SFTP?

Tags: java, apache-camel, sftp, jsch

Apache Camel SFTP implementation uses JSch. But JSch supports only binary file transfer, as I understand from this link:
[How to set file type and file transfer mode in JSch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57920774/how-to-set-file-type-and-file-transfer-mode-in-jsch)

Then how does Camel SFTP support `binary` as an URI parameter?
https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/sftp-component.html

Is my understanding wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation is most likely false.

- Both the `FtpEndpointConfigurer` and the `SftpEndpointConfigurer` indeed propagate the `binary` parameter to `FtpConfiguration.setBinary` and `SftpConfiguration.setBinary` respectively. So in that sense, both *support* that parameter.
- But while `FtpOperations` queries `FtpConfiguration.isBinary` and sets `FtpClient` mode accordingly:

  ```
  client.setFileType(configuration.isBinary() ? FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE : FTP.ASCII_FILE_TYPE);
  ```
- ... the `SftpConfiguration.isBinary` is never called. So the configured value is never used.

Comment: Oh! okay, the documentation was misleading. So, camel ftp implementation uses apache commons ftp client and hence supports both modes. While camel sftp uses jsch and there is only binary mode.
Thank you so much!